# Define language using the time

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i need to define a predefined language, it will be possible to change from Spanish to Portuguese, Spain time is GMT+2 and Portugal GMT+1, the time zone from the server is  GMT+2, so i can know from wich country the user is accessing, and define the language that is more convenient. I was thinking about define a cookie and import a file with some php conditions using AJAX.

What do you suggest? Any hints?

Comment: Why not asking the Accept-Language-header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be more effective to use php's variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`!

Comment: THank you for the tip, but the output from that variable is confusing, i know that needs work to transform the output as variables, but don't know how to do it :(

Comment: the first two letters build the ISO 639-1 alpha-2 code of the language

Answer (score 1):

Like others suggest, you should use the "accept-language" header.

If for some unknown reason you really want to go through the effort of figuring it out by timezone, you can either look up their country by IP, or with the W3C geolocation API, or through a man in the middle page by writing out some javascript that passes in their time.

## Lookup timezone through PHP and Man-In-The-Middle JS

```
session_start();
if($_REQUEST['user_time'])
{
    $_SESSION['user_time'] = $_REQUEST['user_time'];
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_time']))
{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
    echo "document.location.href = '?user_time=' + new Date().getTime();"; 
    echo "</script>";
}
else
{ 
    //normal page execution here
}
```

## W3C Geolocation API

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/how-to-use-the-w3c-geolocation-api/

## Lookup country using Google's geolocation API

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2008/08/two-new-ways-to-location-enable-your.html